# determine how many bytes sent over http

Tags: php

I want users to be able to open certain images from my webserver. I keep a database of which images there are on my server etc.

But I also want to keep track of how many data (in bytes) is used for that specific file. First I thought I just could do `data = data + file_size` but then I realised that most (all) browsers use cache and won't download the full size everytime and will just abort the request half way.

Is there a way in PHP that enables me to determine ***how many bytes were sent over http***?

Thanks.

Comment: Parse your access log.

Comment: It must be efficient. I suppose the file size of an acces logs can really add up

Comment: Then rotate it frequently and parse after rotating.

Comment: You could run everything through PHP output buffering and measure sizes there. But stuff like compression are handled by the server, so that will not give you reliable data. Btw. there is no such thing like clients aborting a connection half-way due to caching. Clients can send HEAD requests, but that does not apply to PHP scripts. And there are dropped connections because of network reasons.